# How to avoid duplicate cookie for my asp.net application

Tags: javascript, asp.net, cookies

I am using a client side cookie to carry a data(string), which is helping to use the same data whenever user reopen the browser. 
My concern there are multiple cookies where created with the same name on the same url(user feels only)
Ex URL:- http://google.com/testapplication

But user is typing the url in case-insensitive, ex as bellow.

1. TestApplication
2. TESTApplication

There is no difference for the user interface, but internally different cookies were created. Could some one help me how to avoid such duplicates.

Thanks
Pavan

Comment: Is it required to use a path on the cookie? Can you post how you are creating the cookie?

Comment: Hi, I am setting cookie in Javascript by using setCookie setCookie("cookiename","value"); and I will read the cookie by using getCookie.. But user typing the URL with different naming conventions in Chrome.. during the Inspect element I had noticed there are multiple cookies created when the user type the URL in different notation.

Comment: Do you have to use the path of the page or would setting the cookie on the root path of the domain suffice?

Comment: I do not have such restriction. it should work(use the same) for all the URL naming cases.. user trying to access the URL name in different naming conventions like camelCase or UpperCamelCase or lowercase or UPPERCASE. I need to use the same cookie for the cases .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cookie Names are case-sensitive for some browsers such as Chrome and FireFox.

In order to avoid it, you should use a single helper method to create cookie, so that cookie name will be consistent across your site.

For example,

```
public class CookieHelper
{
    public static void SetCookie(string cookieName, string cookieValue, int days)
    {
        cookieName = cookieName.ToLower();
        var cookie = new HttpCookie(cookieName)
        {
            Value = cookieValue,
            Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(days)
        };

        HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
    }

    public static String GetCookie(string cookieName)
    {
        try
        {
            cookieName = cookieName.ToLower();    
            if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[cookieName] == null)
                return string.Empty;

            return HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[cookieName].Value;
        }
        catch
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. But my concern not on cookie name .. user trying to access the URL name in different naming conventions like camelCase or UpperCamelCase or lowercase or UPPERCASE. I need to use the same cookie for the cases ...