# Unable to get cookie in ie

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer, cookies

I have stored some UserData in cookie. It works fine in chrome and mozilla. But in IE its unable to get cookie.I am using IE Version 10. Please help me out ?

In Login form :

```
        Dim Mydtt As String = "my custom data "
        Dim authTicket = New FormsAuthenticationTicket(2, usrid, Date.Now, Date.Now.AddDays(7), True, Mydtt, "/")

        Dim cookie As New HttpCookie("usrlg", FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(authTicket))
        Response.Cookies.Set(cookie)
        Response.Redirect("~/phed/reports")
```

In Session Start :

```
        Dim LastLoginCookie As HttpCookie
        LastLoginCookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies.Get("usrlg") ' Return Nothing in IE '
        Dim LastLgTicket As FormsAuthenticationTicket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(LastLoginCookie.Value)
        Dim Mydtt As String = LastLgTicket.UserData
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check for null value before decrypting.

```
Dim LastLoginCookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies("usrlg")

If LastLoginCookie IsNot Nothing Then
   Dim LastLgTicket As FormsAuthenticationTicket = 
      FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(LastLoginCookie.Value)
   Dim Mydtt As String = LastLgTicket.UserData
End If
```

Similar answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22918508/must-declare-the-scalar-variable-email/22918953#22918953).

Comment: Could you try with version 1 and default cookie path - `... New FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, usrid, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddDays(7), true, Mydtt, FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath);` Look at the link in my answer.

Comment: i have tried 
 Dim cookie As New HttpCookie("usrlg", FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(authTicket))
            cookie.Secure = FormsAuthentication.RequireSSL
            cookie.Path = FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath
            cookie.Domain = FormsAuthentication.CookieDomain
            Response.Cookies.Set(cookie)

Comment: Its not working with IE but works fine with Chrome. Any reason why it is happening?

Comment: Does it happens in other computers too? If not, your IE setting might be an issue. ***I'm curious whether regular cookie even work in your IE browser.*** Use [this code](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24957931/296861) to test it.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember `cookie.Secure` must be set correctly, i.e. `false` for HTTP and `true` for HTTPS.
You can use the `Request` object to auto-detect the protocol:

```
cookie.Secure = Request.IsSecureConnection;
Response.Cookies.Set(cookie);
```

Hope this helps.